# Accidentally formatted Ubuntu partition to NTFS. Recover?

Tags: partition, data-recovery

I accidentally formatted my Ubuntu partition in Windows 7 (quick format). Is there any way to recover the partition and data?

Answer (score 1):

It's rather hopeless, but try [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) and [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). `fsck` will most likely not work: at best, it will complain because it doesn't find an ext4 filesystem, at worst it will cause more destruction.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably screwed. Try `fsck -f -t ext#` and see if that finds anything.

Answer (score 0):

TestDisk is likely your best option on this one; it's available on the [RIPLinux live CD](http://rip.7bf.de/current/).